# JS not set variable after loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, loops

I can`t get why in my function not changing value of variable. Here my code.

```
var count = function(datain){
  let temparr = [],
  countobj = {};

  $.each(datain, function(key, val) {
    console.log(temparr);
    countobj.cost = +$(val).find("[name]").text();
    console.log(countobj);
    temparr.push(countobj);
    console.log(temparr);
  });

  console.log(temparr);
  return temparr;
};

let countarr = count(datain);
console.log(countarr);
```

This function part of function that fires on ajax success, ajax i call on some select changes. Datain - result of ajax. At first time call this function work`s fine, but all another fires returns me first time set countarr. All data in key, val - correct, but i cant understand why "countarr" returns me result of first call and not re-set temparr inside function.
Thanks for reply!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're *reusing* the same `countobj` object on each loop, pushing a reference to that single object repeatedly into the array.

You need to create a *new* object on each loop:

```
var count = function(datain) {
    let temparr = [],
        countobj;                                          // ***
    $.each(datain, function(key, val) {
        countobj = {};                                     // ***
        console.log(temparr);
        countobj.cost = +$(val).find("[name]").text();
        console.log(countobj);
        temparr.push(countobj);
        console.log(temparr);
    });
    console.log(temparr);
    return temparr;
};
let countarr = count(datain);
console.log(countarr);
```

As there's just the one property, you don't need a variable. Here's that same code without the variable and with the `console.log` lines removed:

```
var count = function(datain) {
    let temparr = [];
    $.each(datain, function(key, val) {
        temparr.push({cost: +$(val).find("[name]").text()});
    });
    return temparr;
};
let countarr = count(datain);
console.log(countarr);
```

Or you could even use `map`; and since you're using ES2015+ (I can tell from `let`), we can use an arrow function:

```
let count = function(datain) {
    return datain.map(val => ({cost: +$(val).find("[name]").text()}));
};
let countarr = count(datain);
console.log(countarr);
```

If `datain` is only array-like, not an actual array, use `Array.from` instead of `map`:

```
let count = function(datain) {
    return Array.from(datain, val => ({cost: +$(val).find("[name]").text()}));
};
let countarr = count(datain);
console.log(countarr);
```

Comment: Thank you!  That all correct for me and now i see my mistakes! Thank you again!

Comment: Nice! But I guess you can use the second argument in Array.from to use the map implementation instead explicit after dot.